# select 2 tables copy a unique number when records match

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables 1. paypal_ipn_orders table 2 is lookup. The lookup table I have a list of all of my items with the column name item I also have another column labeled sort_id which is an 8 digit number used internally for all of my items. Table 1 paypal_ipn_orders receives orders and has several columns but only a few are important to the question. id, payer_email, item_name, sort_num and payment_status. What I need to happen is when an order comes into table paypal_ipn_orders I need to cross reference the lookup table and assign the 8 digit number into the column labeled sort_num when the item names match.

```
table: paypal_ipn_orders
id       payer_email         item_name        sort_num               payment_status
1        greg@gmail.com      batman card      NULL                    completed
2        steve@gmail.com     superman card    NULL                    completed
3        gary@gmail.com      spiderman card   NULL                    completed
4        sarah@gmail.com     captain america  NULL                    completed
```

here is the sample look up table

```
table: lookup
item                   sort_id
batman card            12345678
superman card          12345677
spiderman card         12345676
captain america        12345675
```

what I want the output to look like after I run the query.

```
table: paypal_ipn_orders
id       payer_email         item_name        sort_num               payment_status
1        greg@gmail.com      batman card      12345678                completed
2        steve@gmail.com     superman card    12345677                completed
3        gary@gmail.com      spiderman card   12345676                completed
4        sarah@gmail.com     captain america  12345675                completed
```

I know this isnt exactly the right syntax but you'll get the idea

```
SELECT lookup.sort_id
INSERT INTO paypal_ipn_orders.sort_num
WHERE lookup.item = paypal_ipn_orders.item_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`:

```
UPDATE paypal_ipn_orders
SET sort_num = (SELECT sort_num
                FROM lookup
                WHERE lookup.item = paypal_ipn_orders.item_name)
```

Two side notes though:

1. Doing this will update the entire table. It would probably be best to do this in a trigger at the time of insert.
2. I wonder the benefit of storing the `sort_num` twice if the `sort_num` will always depend on the value in your `lookup` table. If you are trying to save the value at the time of insert or be able to manually change it though, it makes sense. (That is, if you change the `sort_num`in the `lookup` table, but you want to keep the original values in `paypal_ipn_orders`.)

Comment: the sort id in the lookup table does change from time to time, the orders only get pulled once printed and then dropped which is why I opted to go this route. I appreciate it I'll try that.